# Do you have to use singular and plural nouns after "Any"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, determiners

I want to ask about this specific construction:

> Do you see any error message? 
>   Do you see any error messages?

Are they both grammatically correct? My grammar book says that any should only be used with uncountable or plural nouns.

However, from [Is “any” also used with plurals?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112996/any-followed-by-singular-or-plural-countable-nouns), the top answer says that it still depends on context. I also checked the related thread and they all say the same. [“Any requirement” or “any requirements”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75654/any-requirement-or%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-any-requirements) and [Any individual or any individuals?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111444/any-individual-or%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-any-individuals)

Can the first one mean error message *if there is already a specific error message in mind*? 
While the send one can mean *any error message*?

The problem is, I cannot find grammar books or webpages that says that this is allowed.

Finally, from [Any (Learner's Dictionary)](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/any), I can see that any was used with singular nouns.
*You haven't eaten any salad.*
*You can return the product if any defect appears within the first six months.*

They are all normal sentences though. Do ***any*** have different rules when in questions?

Thank you.

Comment: It would depend on what is expected.  If only one error message may come up, but it is uncertain as to what the message would be, 'any *message*' is appropriate.  If a number of undefined error message*s* could come up, 'any *messages*' is more appropriate.

Comment: The answer is ***any***! We can use singular, plural and uncountable nouns with **any**. See (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/any)

Comment: You will rarely find a dictionary or grammar that will tell you that something is allowed. Generally you should assume it's allowed, especially if a native speaker says it. As for _any_, aside from its being a negative polarity item (so it's OK in questions, _if_-clauses, and negatives, but not otherwise: *_I have any money_), _any_ is just a quantifier like _some_ or _many_ or _all_, and has about the same number of restrictions and idioms as any other quantifier -- i.e, it gets very complicated.